# stack buffer overflow in the main function?

Tags: buffer-overflow

I am trying to exploit a stack based overflow vulnerability. All the examples I can find make use of a `ret` address though. The buffer overflow I found is inside the main function, and I cannot find any examples on how to do this.

The code looks like this:

```
int main(){
   while (1){
   //some code
      switch() {
         case 0:
         char id[128];
         sscanf(buffer,"%s", id);
         break;
      }
   }
}
```

The contents of buffer are controlled by the user.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Have you gotten a segfault?  What exactly are you having trouble with?

Comment: Yes. I managed to get a segfault, i know at how many bytes it segfaults. Than I looked up where my buffer was stored, and added that address reversed to the end of the payload. But than it just segfaults. All the examples i can find online are about returning from a function, and since this is all in the same function, that never happends here. How do I go about executing a payload when it does not return from a function?

Comment: That's a pretty broad question.  It depends on where your overflow is writing to, and what system you're targeting.  Not all buffer overflows are exploitable.

Comment: I can only find examples and information about exploiting buffer overflows in a function call. Could you maybe point me to some information or examples about exploiting an iverflow thats inside the main function?

Comment: I had a look at the same a while back and couldn't work out how to exploit a stack overflow on main. It does depend what other code is in that loop though, and other local variables.

Answer (score 15):

You've run into the hardest part of exploiting a buffer overflow: determining how to get the code to execute. Injecting code is trivial once you've found the vulnerability, but getting the CPU to start executing that code, not so much.

Without a strong understanding of [stack frame layout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_buffer_overflow#Exploiting_stack_buffer_overflows), you will find the rest difficult to follow.

One point of note is that in C, `main`, from the process's viewpoint, is just another function that is called (this is different in C++ see comment below). While you think of it as the beginning of execution, to the CPU it is a full function call with a return address on the stack. So exploiting a flaw in `main` is the same as exploiting a flaw in any other function.

As an attacker, all you can do with a buffer overflow is write to the data section of the process, you need to find a way to have the process read something from data that controls what will be executed. Basically, you need a place in data memory where the process will look to determine what should be executed next (ie: to determine the value of the program counter or PC).

The most common type of locations in data memory that affects the PC are a function's return pointer. When returning from a function, the CPU will read the return pointer off of the stack and set the PC to it (or the instruction after it - details CPU dependent). Unless you return from the `main` function it is very unlikely that you'll execute a successful attack. You'll need some place in data, preferably on the heap, where the processor will read data that is used to set the PC.

The other "common" (tho much less common) places in data memory that are used to exploit a buffer overflow attack are function pointers followed by a function call, and [exception tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_handling) followed by an exception. Neither of these seem applicable to your application. So you probably have a non-exploitable stack buffer overflow vulnerability. The worst I suspect that you can do is crash your app.

The steps the attacker needs to take for a standard stack buffer overflow exploitation are:

1. Identify stack buffer overflow vulnerability.
2. Determine address of stack at time of vulnerability.
3. Determine address of function return pointer in current stack frame.
4. Write code (frequently called [shellcode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellcode)) for attack.
5. Create input that loads code and modifies function return pointer to point to shellcode on stack.

So now that you've found the vulnerability, you need to determine the stack address for call to `main`. The easiest way to do this is to print the address of `id`. Next, the return pointer's location. This is likely two words lower in memory than `id`. Something like `(char *)id-2*sizeof(int)`.

The next step is to write your shellcode. I'd suggest you create a function in your program that prints the string "attack successful" and then exits. Make your shellcode a call to this function.

Now sit down and layout the data on the stack (this [stack frame layout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_buffer_overflow#Exploiting_stack_buffer_overflows) reference should help) including a return address jumping to your `id` variable's buffer. Convert the stack data to ASCII and input it to the program.

[This page](http://www.cse.scu.edu/~tschwarz/coen152_05/Lectures/BufferOverflow.html) has a more concrete example of what I've described.

Comment: You should state that your analysis is done for the C language (only).  In C++, `main` can't be referred to by the program, so the compiler can choose to jump directly to cleanup code rather than actually returning from `main`.  (In C, the compiler can do the same if it can prove the program doesn't call `main` explicitly)

Comment: Note that in my case it never returns from main. It stays in a while(1) loop. As far as I understand overflows, I can only overwrite local variables in this case. Is this correct?

Comment: Ahh. Good point @NoahGoldsmid. I don't think this example is exploitable.I updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: To what location is that `break` in a `case` jumping to? How can you overwrite that address?

Comment: You can't @ott--. The break will jump to an address compiled into the code. You need to attack function return pointers and exception tables because they contain code addresses that are written into the data portion of the process; the only part of the process that can be modified at runtime.